# View Model not containing definition for bootstrap

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to set a page with a viewmodel and some bootstrap elements inside but I'm getting this error.

> CS1061:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper '<'Ebelge.ViewModels.AdminCompanySettingViewModel>'
>        does not contain a definition for 'Bootstrap' and no extension method 'Bootstrap' accepting 
>        a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'<'Ebelge.ViewModels.AdminCompanySettingViewModel'>'
>        could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Line 56:                                       
<h6>Firma Tipi</h6> 
Line 57:                                    
@*@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(t => t.CompanyType).Placeholder("Firma
Tipi")*@  
Line 58:                                    
 @Html.Bootstrap().DropDownListFor(t => t.CompanyType, new
 SelectListItem[] {
```

Line 58 is giving the error

Weird thing is, I have another page which uses same View Model with a different name under another MVC "Area" and it's not giving this error. That page also uses identically coded .cshtml file too.

I tried searching the spots where the working models name is present. It's not pressent in any line like System.Web.Mvc or anyplace which indicates somehow the viewmodel is made to "contain a definition for Bootstrap".

I looked up on other questions but none helped me at all.

Only solution I haven't tried is to install TwitterBootstrapMVC with nuget but that might not be an option for some company related issues.

Does anyone have any idea about how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Bootstrap-namespace in web.config in the views folder for this specific area? Could explain why it is working in one why in a different area, but to in this specific view.